# Not able to enable C++20 on my Mac in VSCode. I updated the existing tasks.json file to run C++20 as standard. But not getting any result

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to enable C++20 on my M1 MacBook Pro 13", but to no result. I am following a tutorial to learn C++ and the instructor told how to enable C++20 on macs (didn't do it practically in the tutorial since he does not have a mac). So I looked up on the VSCode website how to work with clang in VSC, set up VSC to do that.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "-std=c++20",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": "build",
      "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my tasks.json file

The code that the instructor told to run to check if C++20 was this

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
➜ clang++ main.cpp 
main.cpp:10:22: warning: '<=>' is a single token in C++20; add a space to avoid a change in behavior [-Wc++20-compat]
    int result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
                     ^
                        
main.cpp:10:24: error: expected expression
    int result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
                       ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Please help me out

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you were supposed to run?

Comment: The next step is to print out the result. But i am getting the warning that i have mentioned

Comment: I’m not 100% on my cpp 20 features, but I don’t think that exists. Try writing a constinit value. Like `constinit char c = 'a';`

Comment: @Taekahn `<=>` is a [three-way comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) in C++20.

Comment: Could you add `-v` flag and see what the compiler outputs?

Comment: If you ran `clang++ main.cpp` in command line(e.g. Terminal), add a `-std=c++20` option: `clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp`

Comment: Are you running the task you've defined or are you invoking the compiler manually from the terminal?

Comment: What version of that [compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/bMqMGn8dW) do you have installed?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am invoking the compiler from my teriminal

Comment: @VainMan That worked. But is there a way to run C++20 without having to type -std=c++20 everytime?

Comment: Yes, run the task you've defined or use a proper build system to invoke the compiler for you

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error you are experiencing is due to having an older standard (perhaps c++17?) set and attempting to use a feature that was introduced in a later version of the language.

The three-way comparison ('spaceship') operator was introduced in c++20 (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) and requires targeting that standard.

This issue appears to stem from an improperly configured `c_cpp_properties.json`. You can access this in VSCode by typing 'c++ edit configurations' in the command palette.

Once there, ensure the `"cppStandard"` is set to `"c++20"`. Your `json` should end up looking something like this:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "includePath": ["${myDefaultIncludePath}", "/another/path"],
      "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks"],
      "defines": ["FOO", "BAR=100"],
      "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/include/config.h"],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++20",
      "compileCommands": "/path/to/compile_commands.json",
      "browse": {
        "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

(from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference, with `"cppStandard"` updated)